# NOT EXISTS returning no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is **not** a question about the difference between NOT EXISTS and IN.
I just can't seem to get this sql working right.
The logic seems ok, but I'm missing something.
And I have searched everywhere, even in my years and years of notes.

One table named CompanyAccountantRef has 3 fields. ID, CompanyID, and AccountantID.
Currently in the table:

```
ID    CompanyID    AccountantID    
8       6706          346388    
9       6706          346256    
10      6706          26263    
11      363392        358951
```

Then this sql is not bringing back the correct row:

```
DECLARE @CompanyID INT = 363392
DECLARE @AccountIDs TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @AccountIDs (ID) VALUES (358951)
INSERT INTO @AccountIDs (ID) VALUES (26263)

SELECT @CompanyID AS CompanyID, a.ID 
FROM @AccountIDs a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM CompanyAccountantRef
WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID 
AND AccountantID IN (SELECT ID FROM @AccountIDs))
```

It should bring back

```
 CompanyID    AccountantID
    363392       26263
```

And yes, an accountant can have more than one company.
What am I missing here? Is it the use of the IN that breaks it?
I've tried several different way including joins with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: But the expression in the not exists will have and expression or not.  It is not tied to @AccountIDs a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are confused.  Consider the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM CompanyAccountantRef
WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID AND 
      AccountantID IN (SELECT ID FROM @AccountIDs)
```

This returns one row, because `CompanyAccountantRef` has one matching row and its accountant id is `358951`.  There is a match in `@AccountIds`.  Hence, the query returns one row.

Hence, the `NOT EXISTS` is false.  And no rows are returned.

I suspect that you want a correlated subquery of some sort.  I'm not sure what logic you are looking for.  The logic you have doesn't seem particularly useful (either it returns all rows in `@AccountIds` or none).

If I had to guess, you a looking for something like:

```
SELECT @CompanyID AS CompanyID, a.ID 
FROM @AccountIDs a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CompanyAccountantRef car
                  WHERE car.CompanyID = @CompanyID AND
                        car.AccountantID = a.ID
                 );
```

At the very least, this returns the row you are looking for.

Comment: That worked. I didn't want to use a cursor (they are evil). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select @CompanyID, ID 
  from AccountIDs  
except 
select @CompanyID, AccountantID    
  from CompanyAccountantRef 
 where CompanyID = @CompanyID 
   and AccountantID in (SELECT ID FROM @AccountIDs)
```